# Performing FFT on data in xmgrace on command-line startup

Tags: fft, xmgrace

I have a bash script which features reading of an input file by xmgrace. It reads everything in and formats the window correctly. I would also like it to automatically perform an FFT as soon as the data is read in, instead of clicking all the GUI options as I have been doing. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide any code example to show what you have already done and what you would like to do

Comment: I execute xmgrace using `xmgrace -nosafe Input.dat -autoscale x -p params.par` command. The Input.dat file is just a column of numbers, which contains the waveform I would like to Fourier-transform. So what I would like in the end is some command of the form `xmgrace Input.dat -fft`.

Comment: Making some batch file that would perform FFT's and then running it would be fine too! I am a bit confused as to how to implement FFT features in the batch files though.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I made a batch file that read `fft(S0,0)` and ran it with `-batch mybatchfile.bat` command.